# What does this graph mean?

Tags: documentation, group-theory, proof

Mathematica 11.3.0 includes a new command `FindEquationalProof` having good prospects.  Studying it, I consider a somewhat modified example from the help

```
grouptheory = {ForAll[{a, b, c}, g[a, g[b, c]] == g[g[a, b], c]], ForAll[a, g[a, e] == a], 
ForAll[a, g[a, inv[a]] == e], ForAll[a, g[a, a] == e]}
```

, where the assumption `ForAll[a, g[a, a] == e]` that each element of a group has order two is added. I try to prove that such group is Abelian by

```
proof = FindEquationalProof[ForAll[{a, b}, g[a, b] == g[b, a]],  grouptheory]
```

and succeed at this proof. Nice. Next, I visualize the obtained proof by

```
proof["ProofGraph"]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, neither vertices nor arcs are described, so I understand nothing. The documentation about `FindEquationalProof` does not shed light on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with this functionality, but I noticed that hovering a node in the graph reveals its name as a tooltip. Each node is a statement. You can then cross reference them e.g. with `proof["ProofNotebook"]` or `proof["ProofDataset"]` to see what the statement is.

The visual symbol of nodes indicates the type of statement, e.g. green ones are the axioms that were input. Only three of the four axioms you gave here are actually used in this proof.

The arrows pointing to a node show which statements were directly used in its proof.

Solid (non-dashed) arrows appear to be used with substitution lemmas and show where the substitution comes from. It will be substituted into the branch coming from the dashed arrow.

Comment: Thank you. Can you kindly elaborate your answer, explaining  what the left green node at the top of the graph means?

Comment: @user64494 I thought that would be clear after looking at their names. Green ones are all Axioms, orange triangles "Critical Pair Lemma", etc. I am simply guessing from reading the node names. As I said, I am not familiar with this functionality either.

Comment: There are four axioms. Which of them is noticed by the left green node at the top of the graph? The result of proof["ProofDataset"] says nothing about it for me.

Comment: @user64494 I do not understand your comment. The axioms are clearly listed in both the dataset and the (easier to read) notebook for me under the same name as in the graph. I used M11.3.  If your dataset does not contain them, please show a screenshot and indicate your Mathematica version (though I think M11.3 is the only released version with this functionality).

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate your statement "The axioms are clearly listed in both the dataset and the (easier to read) notebook for me under the same name as in the graph"? I repeat my open question "There are four axioms. Which of them is noticed by the left green node at the top of the graph? ". TIA.

Comment: @user64494 Apparently, the axiom `ForAll[a, g[a, inv[a]] == e]` is needed nowhere in the proof; it is superseeded by the idempotence axiom `ForAll[a, g[a, a] == e]`. I suspect that the output of `FindEquationalProof` are meant to be minimal in some sense and that this minimality is why the axiom `ForAll[a, g[a, inv[a]] == e]` just does not appear in the returned `ProofObject`.

Comment: @user64494 I hover the green thing with the mouse, I see "Axiom 1". Then I go to the proof notebook, there is a heading "Axiom 1", with the axiom written below it. Please post a screenshot of your proof notebook if these do not appear for you.

Comment: Thank you. I confirm that behavior. It should be documented.